# Strong type verification failures running unit tests on ASP.NET webapp

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, code-coverage

Whenever I try running unit tests in Visual Studio, I get the following warnings on a number of my tests, which cause them to fail:

> Strong name verification failed for the instrumented assembly '*FULL
>   ASSEMBLY NAME REFERENCED IN WEB APP PROJECT*'. Please ensure that the
>   right key file for re-signing after instrumentation is specified in
>   the test settings.`

Note that the *FULL ASSEMBLY NAME REFERENCED IN WEB APP PROJECT* is a library assembly that we are using from a third-party.

The interesting thing is the assembly warnings above appear in *all* tests that use *FULL ASSEMBLY NAME REFERENCED IN WEB APP PROJECT*, not just ones that are exercising the web app project.  We reference this assembly in multiple projects.

I find that removing the web application from code coverage in my test settings file causes the test failures to go away...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround:

I unchecked the ASP.NET webapp from code coverage in the testsettings, and then added the regular assembly for the webapp into code coverage.

All of the tests passed, and I was still able to get code coverage metrics from the webapp assembly.